# JCheckBox, create an event once selection is submitted and print a graphic drawing to GUI frame

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

First include a frame with a text fields, one for name submission, a submit button and check boxes for eyes, a nose and mouth. When the button is clicked, display your face, including the submitted name below the face. If eyes and nose only were checked, then set the size for each and draw components to represent those features.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;    
import javax.swing.JFrame;    
import    java.awt.FlowLayout;    
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;    import javax.swing.JTextArea;    
import javax.swing.JTextField;    import java.awt.Color;    
import java.awt.Graphics;    import java.awt.SystemColor;    
import javax.swing.JButton;    import javax.swing.SwingConstants;   
import java.awt.Font; import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JLabel;import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.GridLayout;import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;

public class FACE extends JFrame {

private JFrame frame;
private JTextField textField;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                FACE window = new FACE();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }});
}
public FACE() {
    initialize();
}
//Initialize the contents of the frame & set layout, meets requirement 5.5,
//Use layout managers to arrange user-interface components in a container
//Requirement 5.2 Add buttons, text fields, and other components to a frame window
private void initialize() {
    FaceGraphic component = new FaceGraphic(rootPaneCheckingEnabled, rootPaneCheckingEnabled, rootPaneCheckingEnabled);
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Face O Matic"); 
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 352, 310);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTextArea txtrName = new JTextArea();
    txtrName.setBounds(69, 5, 51, 26);
    txtrName.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    txtrName.setEditable(false);
    txtrName.setBackground(SystemColor.control);
    txtrName.setText("Name :");

    JLabel label = new JLabel("");
    label.setBounds(125, 18, 0, 0);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(130, 8, 126, 20);
    textField.setColumns(15);

    JLabel lblPlease = new JLabel("Please choose from the following to create a face!");
    lblPlease.setBounds(5, 36, 305, 19);
    lblPlease.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 13));

    // create check boxes
    JCheckBox chckbxEyes = new JCheckBox("Eyes");
    chckbxEyes.setBounds(17, 76, 51, 27);
    chckbxEyes.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    chckbxEyes.setSelected(false);

    JCheckBox chckbxNose = new JCheckBox("Nose");
    chckbxNose.setBounds(69, 76, 53, 27);
    chckbxNose.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    chckbxNose.setSelected(false);

    JCheckBox chckbxMouth = new JCheckBox("Mouth");
    chckbxMouth.setBounds(130, 76, 59, 27);
    chckbxMouth.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    chckbxMouth.setSelected(false);

    // label that states "Nice face" and than name once user hits submit
    JLabel lblNiceFace = new JLabel("Nice face");
    lblNiceFace.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    lblNiceFace.setBounds(177, 240, 133, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNiceFace);

    JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
    btnSubmit.setBounds(220, 75, 90, 27);
    btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


        // Handle events that are generated by buttons, meets
        // Requirement 5.3
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            // print name to niceFace label from textField once user inputs and hits submit
            String name = textField.getText();
            lblNiceFace.setText("Nice face " + name + "!");
        }
    });
    //add button, labels, check boxes, etc.. to contentPane
    btnSubmit.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtrName);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblPlease);
    frame.getContentPane().add(chckbxEyes);
    frame.getContentPane().add(chckbxNose);
    frame.getContentPane().add(chckbxMouth);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnSubmit);  
    frame.getContentPane().add(component);  

}
```

}

Hello, I am fairly new to GUI and this is what I have so far. What I am having issues with is being able to connect and create an event listener to my check boxes and once i hit submit, the graphics to create a smiley face appear at there given coordinates; this is what I have for a face graphics class.

```
   import java.awt.Color;
   import java.awt.Graphics;
   import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FaceGraphic extends JPanel {
private boolean hasEyes;
private boolean hasNose;
private boolean hasMouth;

public FaceGraphic(boolean hasEyes, boolean hasNose, boolean hasMouth) {
    setParameters(hasEyes, hasNose, hasMouth);
}

public void setParameters(boolean hasEyes, boolean hasNose, boolean hasMouth) {
    this.hasEyes = hasEyes;
    this.hasNose = hasNose;
    this.hasMouth = hasMouth;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.fillOval(100, 100, 100, 100); // head

    g.setColor(Color.black);

    if (hasEyes) {            
        g.fillOval(120, 125, 20, 20); // left eye
        g.fillOval(160, 125, 20, 20); // right eye
    }
    if (hasNose)
        g.drawLine(150, 165, 150, 150); // nose

    if (hasMouth)
        g.drawArc(120, 130, 60, 60, 0, -180); // mouth
    }
}
```

How do I go about getting my submit Button to draw a image of no matter what the head, and either the eyes, nose or mouth or all, etc.

update as of 10/27/16

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    import javax.swing.*;

    public class CheckBoxDemo extends JPanel
                      implements ItemListener {
JCheckBox eyes;
JCheckBox nose;
JCheckBox mouth;

StringBuffer choices;
private JTextField textField;

public CheckBoxDemo() {
    choices = new StringBuffer("cght");
            setLayout(null);

            nose = new JCheckBox("Nose");
            nose.setBounds(92, 57, 69, 23);
            add(nose);
            //nose.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_G);
            nose.setSelected(false);
            nose.addItemListener(this);

            mouth = new JCheckBox("Mouth");
            mouth.setBounds(186, 57, 69, 23);
            add(mouth);
            //mouth.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_H);
            mouth.setSelected(false);
            mouth.addItemListener(this);

            //Create the check boxes.
            eyes = new JCheckBox("Eyes");
            eyes.setBounds(6, 57, 69, 23);
            add(eyes);
            //eyes.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
            eyes.setSelected(false);
            eyes.addItemListener(this);

            JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Please choose from the following to create a face!");
            lblNewLabel.setBounds(6, 11, 312, 14);
            add(lblNewLabel);

            JLabel lblPleaseEnterYour = new JLabel("Please enter your name: ");
            lblPleaseEnterYour.setBounds(6, 36, 155, 14);
            add(lblPleaseEnterYour);

            textField = new JTextField();
            textField.setBounds(153, 30, 100, 20);
            add(textField);
            textField.setColumns(10);

            JLabel lblNiceFace = new JLabel("");
            lblNiceFace.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
            lblNiceFace.setBounds(153, 240, 133, 20);
            add(lblNiceFace);

            JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
            btnSubmit.setBounds(28, 240, 89, 23);
            btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


                // Handle events that are generated by buttons, meets
                // Requirement 5.3
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    // print name to niceFace label from textField once user inputs and hits submit
                    String name = textField.getText();
                    lblNiceFace.setText("Nice face " + name + "!");
                }});
            add(btnSubmit);
}
/** Listens to the check boxes. */
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    int index = 0;
    char c = '-';
    Object source = e.getItemSelectable();

    if (source == eyes) {
        index = 0;
        c = 'c';
    } else if (source == nose) {
        index = 1;
        c = 'g';
    } else if (source == mouth) {
        index = 2;
        c = 'h';
    }

    //Now that we know which button was pushed, find out
    //whether it was selected or not.
    if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
        c = '-';
    }

    //Apply the change to the string.
    choices.setCharAt(index, c);
    repaint();
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.fillOval(100, 100, 100, 100); // head

    g.setColor(Color.black);

    if (eyes.isSelected()) {            
        g.fillOval(120, 125, 20, 20); // left eye
        g.fillOval(160, 125, 20, 20); // right eye
    }
    if (nose.isSelected())
        g.drawLine(150, 165, 150, 150); // nose

    if (mouth.isSelected())
        g.drawArc(120, 130, 60, 60, 0, -180); // mouth
}

public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("FaceOMatic");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (350, 325));

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    JComponent newContentPane = new CheckBoxDemo();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

When you want to draw the face, you need the name and whether to draw eyes, nose and/or mouth. I would create a separate class for the `FaceGraphic` that can be constructed with these parameters. You can add the name to the graphic by using the `drawString` method.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FaceGraphic extends JPanel {
    private String name;
    private boolean hasEyes;
    private boolean hasNose;
    private boolean hasMouth;

    public FaceGraphic(String name, boolean hasEyes, boolean hasNose, boolean hasMouth) {
        setParameters(name, hasEyes, hasNose, hasMouth);
    }

    public void setParameters(String name, boolean hasEyes, boolean hasNose, boolean hasMouth) {
        this.name = name;
        this.hasEyes = hasEyes;
        this.hasNose = hasNose;
        this.hasMouth = hasMouth;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paintComponent(graphics);

        graphics.setColor(Color.yellow);

        // head
        graphics.fillOval(100, 100, 100, 100);

        graphics.setColor(Color.black);

        // name
        graphics.drawString(name, 150, 50);

        if (hasEyes) {
            // left eye
            graphics.fillOval(120, 125, 20, 20);
            // right eye
            graphics.fillOval(160, 125, 20, 20);
        }

        if (hasNose)
            // nose
            graphics.drawLine(150, 165, 150, 150);

        if (hasMouth)
            // mouth
            graphics.drawArc(120, 130, 60, 60, 0, -180);
    }
}
```

**Edit: example of calling `setParameters`**

You could add a call to the `setParameters` method in the event handler of the submit button:

```
JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
btnSubmit.setBounds(220, 75, 90, 27);
btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    // Handle events that are generated by buttons, meets
    // Requirement 5.3
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        // print name to niceFace label from textField once user inputs and hits submit
        String name = textField.getText();
        lblNiceFace.setText("Nice face " + name + "!");

        component.setParameters(name, chckbxEyes.isSelected(),
                                  chckbxNose.isSelected(), chckbxMouth.isSelected());
        component.repaint();
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay, I thought that is what I would have to do; create a separate class to hold my graphic components.. Now what I also am confused on is how to get them to print once my check boxes are clicked and user hits submit button. And than also I want to take away the printing name input to console and print it to label after it says, "Nice face".

Comment: Update; I was able to print the name to my label place at the bottom of my frame. So now my only issue is with getting my separate class to listen to the "submit" button for the checkboxes along with my users name.

Comment: You can now create an instance of the `FaceGraphic` class in your application and add it to the content pane. When the user presses the submit button, you can change all parameters of the `faceGraphic` instance (by passing the name and the "is selected" values of the check boxes) and tell it to repaint itself. I've added a `setParameters` method as an example to the class above.

Comment: I apologize I am still not able to complete this code as I would like. I did update and create an instance of the FaceGraphic class in my Face class,  instance() method. I was able to print the name to the label I wanted when the user hits submit. Now I am still working on somehow passing the name and the chckbxEyes.isSelected lets say and telling it to repaint.

Comment: The code in your question is completely updated? When the user presses the submit button, the name and check box values should be sent to the face graphic. I would expect a call to the `setParameters` method of the `FaceGraphic` in the `actionPerformed` method for the submit button. After setting the parameters, a call to the `repaint` method of the face graphic should make the changes visible.

Comment: No, I stated I have not got it where I want it to be yet. But here is an update. I started with another code example and now still confused on instead of printing graphics when the checkbox is selected to printing the name in a label at the bottom along with the selected checkboxes.  .. *** see the most recent edit.